# Variables need global scope, but avoid Implicitly Unwrapped Optionals

Tags: ios, swift, option-type

I need some variables to be defined with a global scope so various functions through my ViewController class can access them.

I found, and followed, some tutorials / articles / references online that are explaining the same thing - Swift, iOS, CoreML and the camera for image processing / classification. More than one of these says something along the lines of "we know the vars will exist and have this datatype, so its ok to add '!' ". However, just learning Swift, I understand and would like to adhere to the design principles of not using '!'.

So I start off declaring the variables with `var varName : ClassType!` and then set the value at a later execution point. It is always set before being accessed (one of the "rules" of Implicitly Unwrapped Optionals I have seen in other articles).

If I declared them within the function(s) they are needed in, only that function has access to them. But I need to access them across the ViewController.

The skeleton structure I have:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {

    // MARK: Global Variables
    var layer: CALayer {
        return viewCamera.layer
    }
    var isCameraRunning = false

    // INIT Camera Variables. Used by multiple functions, so global scope
    var cameraSession : AVCaptureSession!
    var device : AVCaptureDevice!
    var cameraLayer : AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!
    var cameraOutput : AVCaptureVideoDataOutput!
    var cameraInput : AVCaptureDeviceInput!

    // MARK: IB Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var labelInfo: UILabel! // provides user with status info
    @IBOutlet weak var viewCamera: UIView! // a simple UIView on the storyboard

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.viewCameraTap))
        viewCamera.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

    }

    @objc func viewCameraTap() {

        if isCameraRunning {

            // STOP CAMERA (AND PROCESSING)
            cameraRelease()

            // RESET UI
            labelInfo.text = "Default text"

        } else {

            // INIT CAMERA
            // START CAMERA, contained within cameraInit()
            // PROCESS IMAGE CLASSIFICATION, contained within captureOutput()
            cameraInit()


            // UPDATE UI
            labelInfo.text = "Processing"


        }

        isCameraRunning = !isCameraRunning // Toggles the value after processing the function
    }

    // MARK: Camera Init & Release

    func cameraInit() {

        cameraSession = AVCaptureSession()
        cameraSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.photo

        device = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: AVMediaType.video)

        do {
            cameraInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device!)

            if cameraSession.canAddInput(cameraInput) {
                cameraSession.addInput(cameraInput)
            }
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

        cameraOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
        if cameraSession.canAddOutput(cameraOutput) {
            cameraSession.addOutput(cameraOutput)
        }

        cameraLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: cameraSession)
        cameraLayer?.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill

        cameraLayer.frame = layer.frame
        cameraLayer.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        layer.addSublayer(cameraLayer)

        cameraOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue(label: "videoQueue"))

        cameraSession.startRunning()

    }

    func cameraRelease() {
        if cameraSession != nil {
            if cameraSession.isRunning {

                cameraSession.stopRunning()
                cameraSession.removeInput(cameraInput)
                cameraSession.removeOutput(cameraOutput)
                cameraOutput = nil
                cameraLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
                cameraSession = nil
            }
        }
    }

    // MARK: Camera Capture

    func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {

        processCameraBuffer(sampleBuffer: sampleBuffer) { result in

            print("result: \(result)")
        }
    }

    func processCameraBuffer(sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, completion: @escaping (Float) -> Void) {

        var result : Float = 0.0
        // some processing, etc...

        completion(result)
    }

}
```

What would be the best / preferred / recommended way to make the variables global in scope, but not Implicitly Unwrapped Optionals?

If I set a variable like:
`var cameraSession : AVCaptureSession?`

Then in the `cameraInit()`, I cannot use the `guard let newVarName` or `if let newVarName` as this `newVarName` object will be limited in scope and is also using a different name.

At the top of `cameraInit()`, I could put: `cameraSession = AVCaptureSession()` to initialise it. But all future references to `cameraSession` need to be Optionally Chained (i.e. trailing 'cameraSession?')

Or, with this scenario, is it acceptable to use Implicitly Unwrapped Optionals? I know this variable isn't accessed before being set, and I know the data type it will have.

Comment: Those aren't global variables, they're contained in an instance of a class. The scope is that instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should prefer using optional before implicitly unwrapped optional.

Therefore use following:

```
var cameraSession : AVCaptureSession?
```

Then whenever you need to use it, you can use one of the following:

1. If there is only one occurrence, you can use optional chaining:

   ```
   cameraSession?.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.photo
   ```
2. If there are multiple occurrences, and/or the `cameraSession` is used on the right hand side (so a value is needed, not just optional):

   ```
   guard let cameraSession = cameraSession else { return }
   // from now till the end of scope (in this case the method) you
   // can use cameraSession as a non optional type
   cameraSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.photo

   ...
   ```

> Then in the `cameraInit()`, I cannot use the `guard let newVarName` or `if let newVarName` as this `newVarName` object will be limited in scope and is also using a different name.

So what? The scope is limited for the given variable, not for the instance it points to. In that scope you can access it as if it was not optional. Yes, you will need to use `if let cameraSession = cameraSession` or `guard let cameraSession = cameraSession` everywhere where you need to use `cameraSession`, but that's the price you have to pay for the type safety (and it is a very small price considering what you get for it).

**UPDATE**

`cameraRelease` is a bit tricky.

If let solution:

```
func cameraRelease() {
    if let cameraSession = cameraSession {
        if cameraSession.isRunning {

            cameraSession.stopRunning()
            cameraSession.removeInput(cameraInput)
            cameraSession.removeOutput(cameraOutput)
            cameraOutput = nil
            cameraLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
        }
    }
    // this you have to put outside, because here you are trying to assign 
    // something to the cameraSession instance property, not to the local
    // variable created by if let
    cameraSession = nil
}
```

Guard let solution:

```
func cameraRelease() {
    guard let cameraSession = cameraSession else { return }
    if cameraSession.isRunning {
        cameraSession.stopRunning()
        cameraSession.removeInput(cameraInput)
        cameraSession.removeOutput(cameraOutput)
        cameraOutput = nil
        cameraLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
    }
    // use self.cameraSession instead of cameraSession to refer to
    // instance property and not to the local variable created by guard let
    self.cameraSession = nil
}
```

P.S.: You should change to optionals all the variables that you have created (you can leave `@IBOutlet`s as implicitly unwrapped).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, background and explains @Milan. I have used the `guard let` method, which seems to work as expected, except for the cameraRelease() function. New error is "Nil value cannot be assigned to type 'AVCaptureSession'" when try to set `cameraSession = nil` - all I have done is place a `guard let cameraSession = cameraSession else { return }` line at top of the function

Comment: thanks for the assistance and explanations, @Milan. The intention was to go through each var, which I have now done. The only one that caused another issue was `cameraInput`, which when set did not like a `guard` statement, so had to use an `if let` inside the `do` statement. Also `device` is only used on 1 line, so thought I could use an appending '?', but had to write it's own `guard` statement as well.

Comment: @jingo_man I would use `?` anywhere where I can, if it is just one line, it's the same as `if let`